Dependancies between models in asp.net - supply object to another model
I'm studying asp.net MVC and i have difficulties to understand how models work together.
I have a HTML forms under a specific model, and i want user to select an object from another model with a listbox.
Let's say i have a model called "companies", which already have company A, company B & company C in database, that include Name, Address ... as properties.
Now, i have another model Loans, which is basically companies loaning to each other.
I built a HTML form where user can register a New Loan with different properties. Two of those properties are : "From Company" "To Company". User will have ListBox on those two properties, that shows list of Companies in Database : Company A, Company B...
What is the best way to do that ? How does models are linking to each other ? One company can have multiple Loans (Loaner or Borrower), but a Loan can only have One Loaner & One Borrower.
EDIT : I use EntityFrameWork & SQLite
Some code to start:
Models:
namespace App.Models
{
  public class Companies
     {
        public string Id{get;set;}
        public string Name{get;set;}
        public string Address{get;set;}
     }
}

namespace App.Models
{
  public class Loan
     {
        public string Id{get;set;}
        public int amount{get;set;}
        public string FromCompany{get;set;}
        public string ToCompany{get;set;}
     }
}

controller
namespace App.Controllers
{
    public class LoansController:Controller
    {
        private readonly LoansContext _context;

        public LoansController(LoansContext context){
            _context = context;
        }
    }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoansAdd()
        {   
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoansAdd([Bind("Id,fromEntity",
                                                        "toEntity",
                                                        "amount",
                                                         )]Loans loan)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(loan);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(LoansOverview));
            }
            return View(loan);         
        }
}

Html Form
@model App.Models.Loans
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="LoansAdd">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <div class = "col-md-6">
                        <div class = "form-group">
                            <div>
                            <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
                            <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control"/>
                            <span asp-validation-for="Id" class = "text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            <label asp-for="fromEntity" class="control-label"></label>
                            <input asp-for="fromEntity" class="form-control"/>
                            <span asp-validation-for="fromEntity" class = "text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            <label asp-for="toEntity" class="control-label"></label>
                            <input asp-for="toEntity" class="form-control"/>
                            <span asp-validation-for="toEntity" class = "text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                            <label asp-for="amount" class="control-label"></label>
                            <input asp-for="amount" class="form-control"/>
                            <span asp-validation-for="amount" class = "text-danger"></span>
                            </div>
     </div>



got a little bit lost with all solution i see, but i guess there should be properties that models share, like adding Loan properties on Company model

The simple way is to use a reference to refer to the companies :
public class Loan
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public int Amount {get;set;}
    public Company From {get;set;}
    public Company To {get;set;}
}

You can also add the loans to the companies:
public class Company
{
    public string Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Address{get;set;}
    public List<Loan> Loans {get;} = new List<Loan>();
}

And a method to make sure everything is created and added correctly:
public static void CreateLoan(Company from, Company to, int amount){
    var loan = new Loan(){From = from, To = to, Amount = amount};
    from.Loans.Add(loan);
    to.Loans.Add(loan);
}

In real life you would likely use a database to store all the companies and loans, and something like Entity Framework to convert the database rows from and to objects. This adds a bit of complexity since you want to have some control of fetching and saving data to the database, but it would still model the relations between companies and loans in a similar way.

My bad, forgot to mention - I indeed use EntityFrameWork and SQLite (for time being).
How would be the best way to manage this ?

@Thibault_Km When you load data from EF you can use .Include(...) to tell if a relation should be fetched. You probably also want to use longs for IDs. See EF relationships for an introduction, you probably want to spend some time reading the documentation and follow tutorials to get comfortable with how EF should be used. It is not something easily covered in a SO post.

Thanks a lot Jonas, i'll spend times learning EntityFrameWork properly.
In between ChatGPT helped me today (after a lot of confusion) achieving .Include method :)
